# Excel Concatenate and IF Functions

Tags: excel-2010

I need to combine these cells (columns) A and B if the Column C is "Dry" and "Water" and if the carrier is "Maersk" and "Lloyd". Thank you in advance!

Sample data from Excel File:

[image: Sample data from Excel File]

Answer (score 0):

To me, it sounds like you need to write a basic Excel formula to check that the values of the target columns fall in the allowable ranges. This will require using a combination of the `AND` and `OR` functions. Something like this...

Formula for Cell E1:

```
=IF(AND(OR(C1="WATER",C1="DRY"),OR(D1="Maersk",D1="Lloyd")),A1&B1,"-")
```